# extraer varios datos de 3 tablas

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, datatable, sql

Tengo una tabla de proveedores, clientes y usuarios (dentro de usuarios tengo un campo tipo: si es vendedor, administrador y supervisor). Tengo que hacer una tabla donde en un listado tenga todos los nombres que aparezcan en estas 3 tablas y definir que son : si clientes/proveedores/vendedor etc etc. 
Como puedo realizar esto? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: con un inner join entre las 3 tablas te deberia bastar.

Comment: Tal vezesto te pueda ayudar https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es llenar una tabla a partir de otras tablas esta sintaxis te puede ayudar:

```
INSERT INTO tabla_comun(nombre, tipo_tabla)
SELECT nombre, 'cliente' FROM cliente;
```

[Fuente](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: muchas gracias! Que seria tipo_tabla? . Mira tengo mi tabla cliente(id_cliente,nombre, etc), lo mismo con proveedor y usuarios. Creo que mi problema esta en no saber como relacionar esas tres tablas. Como resultado debo tener un listado por ejemplo nombre:juanito tipo:cliente y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: @milagros tipo_tabla seria el tipo de usuario para tu caso y la tabla_comun seria la tabla que quieres llenar con la data que estas utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un inner join, te dejo la sintaxis.

```
SELECT a.ValorTabla1, b.ValorTabla2, c.ValorTabla3 FROM a Tabla1 INNER JOIN b Tabla2 INNER JOIN c Tabla3 WHERE (aqui tu le dices que debe traer, ejemplo) ID = ID2
```

las a, b y c que puse es para saber si traera a.DATO de a.TABLA